# robots.txt parser java

Tags: java, parsing, robots.txt

I want to know how to parse the robots.txt in java.

Is there already any code?

Answer (score 5):

[Heritrix](http://crawler.archive.org/) is an open-source web crawler written in Java.  Looking through their javadoc, I see that they have a utility class [Robotstxt](http://crawler.archive.org/apidocs/org/archive/crawler/datamodel/Robotstxt.html) for parsing the robots.txt file.

Comment: There is a bug in Robotstxt. Please do not use it. Wasted a lot of time. To a file like this : 
User-agent : *  
Disallow: / 
AllowAll method of Robotstxt says "true".

Answer (score 2):

There's also [jrobotx library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jrobotx/) hosted at SourceForge.

(Full disclosure: I spun off the code that forms that library.)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a new release of crawler-commons:

https://github.com/crawler-commons/crawler-commons

The library aims to implement functionality common to any web crawler and this includes a very handy robots.txt parser