# Accessing robots.txt file in java

Tags: java, web-crawler, robots.txt

I am new in java.I want to make a simple web crawler.how to access a robots.txt file for a website in java.actually i dont know much about robots.txt. plz help me out.

Comment: The robots.txt file is in a pretty standard location on every single website (since any given number of various search engines need to be able to find it).  Accessing it is as simple as performing a get of [url]/robots.txt  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve two tasks:

1. use a HTTP library to fetch files over HTTP -- [How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)
2. write or use a parser for robots.txt files -- [robots.txt parser java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141031/robots-txt-parser-java)